# Destroying the Invoking Instance

Tags: c++, oop, delete-operator

I am new to the OOP scene for lack of a better term.

So here is an class example

```
class Example{
public:
    Example(const char *);
    ~Example(); //Calls Destroy in Body
    Example & copy(const char *);
    Example & copy(const Example &);
private:
    void destroy();
    char * data;
    unsigned int size;
};
```

Here is an example of the temporary objects I am talking about below.

```
    Example & Example::copy(const Example & oldString) {
    size = oldString.getSize();
    data = new(std::nothrow) char[size];
    if (data != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
            data[i] = oldString.data[i];
        }
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Data could not be initiallized with a size of" << oldString.getSize() << std::endl;
    }
    destroy();
    return *this;
}
Example & Example::copy(const char * oldString){
    Example newCopyString(oldString);
    copy(newCopyString);
    return *this;
}
```

There are many functions that create temporary objects to convert a `char *` that is passed in to a `Example` object.

So I need a way to delete this object in `copy(const char * oldString)`.

As the questions says, I am trying to `delete` the invoking instance and I don't know how.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What are you trying to delete? The invoking instance of class Example or the const char* passed into the constructor. Please provide an implementation of the methods and example usage.

Comment: what is *invoking instance*?

Comment: Rather than providing the methods themselves you should probably explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The loop with `i <= size` writes off the end of the buffer

Comment: The temporary object `newCopyString` in `copy(const char*)` was created with automatic storage duration (a local "stack" value), so its destructor is automatically called when it goes out of scope -- at the end of the function.  So its `~Example()` will be called, which you claim calls `destroy()`.  So somewhere in there, you need to maybe `delete [] data;` or do someting else to manage the class' dynamic storage.  By the way, in `copy(const Example &)`, the for loop copies past the end of `data`'s allocated memory.

Comment: " I am trying to delete the invoking instance" - don't do this and it is not possible anyway. Your code is all backwards.

Comment: Instead of having `copy`  methods, use copy construction `Example( Example const& )` and copy asignment `Example& operator=( Example const&)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally speaking an object can commit suicide by doing

```
delete this;
```

recommending this as a good practice is a completely different matter... in general is not a very good idea, it probably indicates some fault in the way you organize memory management.

Comment: Would this work in my updated question where I put a couple of functions that I have been working on in my application?

Comment: What you are doing looks very weird. What is the pourpose of  `Example & copy(const char *);`? Why not just using the constructor `Example(const char *);`?